# Change word-document to the input from a GUI?

Tags: microsoft-word, gui, input, auto-form-fill

Every now and then I have to update some rent-contracts which I do by hand. Is there a way I could create a program / app / gui that asks me for input and then changes those values in the (word) document?

So for example, if I open the gui, it will show something like:
name tenant:
rent fee:
start date:
end date:

And I could fill that in then and it would automatically give me the word document with the right values.

Is there a way I could program this or what would be recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Mailing option in Word.

The Main function of this ribbon it to take given data and put it in given locations,
then you can change the data and with one click the file will change too.

[How to use Mailing in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)

[How to make the best Excel file for Mailing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/prepare-your-excel-data-source-for-a-word-mail-merge-2d802b6b-a3a3-43e5-bb76-2c)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a form with fillable fields for the data that you want repeated
in the document.

When a form is created, the field is assigned a bookmark name.
Through the use of other bookmark-related fields, you may then
reference the field elsewhere in the document, thus duplicating its content
in more than one place.

This also allows tabbing through all the fields in order
by using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and also (if required) protecting the
non-fillable text against modifications.

The Developer Tab is used when creating the form.
With it one creates fillable fields, but also other content controls
such as drop-down lists.

For more details, see these references (but many more can easily be found):

- [Create forms that users complete or print in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b)
- [Working with Form Fields](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008303_Working_with_Form_Fields.html)
- [Repeating text within a document](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/word-repeating-text-within-a-document/)